# SUM for more fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I have a query,which give me wrong result.Here is my query.

```
SELECT sum(open1) open1, sum(closed1) closed,sum(pending1) NotSpecified, 
       status,type,sub_status,created_date,bystatus,lst_type 
FROM ( 
  SELECT agent_1_id,status,type,sub_status,created_date,'Open' as bystatus, 
         (CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 'Rent' 
               WHEN type = 2 THEN 'Sale' 
          ELSE 'Not Specified' END) as lst_type, 
         count(*) as open1, 0 closed1, 0 pending1 
  FROM crm_mydeals 
  where status = 1 AND agent_1_id>0 and is_active=1 
  GROUP BY status 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT agent_1_id,status,type,sub_status,created_date,'Closed' as bystatus,
         (CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 'Rent' 
               WHEN type = 2 THEN 'Sale' 
          ELSE 'Not Specified' END) as lst_type, 
         0 open1, count(*) as closed1, 0 pending1 
  FROM crm_mydeals 
  where status = 2 AND agent_1_id>0 and is_active=1 
  GROUP BY status 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT agent_1_id,status,type,sub_status,created_date,'NotSpecified' as bystatus,
         (CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 'Rent' 
               WHEN type = 2 THEN 'Sale' 
          ELSE 'Not Specified' END) as lst_type, 
         0 open1, 0 closed1, count(*) as pending1 
  FROM crm_mydeals 
  where status = 3 AND agent_1_id>0 and is_active=1 
  GROUP BY status 
) s
WHERE DATE(created_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-22' AND '2014-2-22' 
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: With this non trivial query, it's very hard to guess what the result is _supposed_ to be. You'll need to describe the problem in much more detail than "wrong result"

Comment: Wrong result means sum(open1) open1, sum(closed1) closed,sum(pending1) NotSpecified is not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simplify the query, it might help to find the correct answer?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS open1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS closed,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS NotSpecified, 
       status,
       type,
       sub_status,
       created_date,
       (CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 'Open'
             WHEN status = 2 THEN 'Closed'
             WHEN status = 3 THEN 'NotSpecified') AS bystatus,
       (CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN 'Rent' 
             WHEN type = 2 THEN 'Sale' 
             ELSE 'Not Specified' END) as lst_type
FROM crm_mydeals 
WHERE status IN (1,2,3)
AND agent_1_id > 0
AND is_active=1 
AND DATE(created_date) BETWEEN '2013-11-22' AND '2014-2-22' 
GROUP BY status, type, sub_status, created_date
```